# How to create a file for serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

I need to write a method to take an array of objects and serialize them into a file. My question is how do I check to see if the file is there and if the file is not, it will create a file then serialize the objects to it?

Comment: And if it is there?

Comment: **Check this link out** <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291785/check-if-file-exists-without-creating-it">Posible duplicate of this question</a>

Comment: @smacaz Duplicate of a small part of this question.

Comment: @smacaz take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61072) ;)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the object is serializable, and you have [Apache Commons OI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), you can use [`SerializationUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) and [`FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
File file = new File(<file>)
if(!file.exists()){
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile (file, SerializationUtils.serialize(<obj>));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File#exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) and [`File#createNewFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile()):

```
File file = new File("C:/...");

if(file.exists()){
   // ...
} else {
   file.createNewFile();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, so if this program is ran on another users console it can read it from the program and not from a path stored on the computer. Does that make sense? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @QuintonThompson you can read a resource file using `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`, although *creating* a resource file is a whole nother topic. See [Add files in jar during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763449/add-files-in-jar-during-runtime)

Comment: @QuintonThompson So when you clearly say 'file' in your question you now mean 'not a file'. Please clarify.

Comment: `File.createNewFile()` does not accomplish the stated objective.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `new File("path").exists()`, that has already been pointed out there is `Files.exists(path)` that takes the `Path` object that you will need to construct. Which one you want to use depends on the way the file path arrives in your application (whichever is simpler is the correct solution for you).

Answer (score -1):

Using Java 8 File API

```
final Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("file:/C:/temp/test.txt"));
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
// add your objects here
objOut.writeObject(new Object());
Files.write(path, out.toByteArray(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```